# How to serialize dict in Django?

Tags: python, django, serialization

I can't figure out how to serialize `cleaned_data` of some form. The problem probably is, that this `cleaned_data` contains `model objects`. I didn't find anything touching this problem so I'm asking here.

> Exception Value:
>   'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Is there some simple way or Django built-in function?

My cleaned_data:

```
{'notes': u'dsads', 'language_from': <Language: Slovak>, 'file': None, 'short_description': u'dsadsad', 'text_to_translate': u'dsads', 'delivery_date': datetime.date(1930, 1, 1)}
```

This is a `formset` cleaned_data:

```
[{'language': <Language: Magyar>, 'level': <Level: Standard level>}, 
 {'language': <Language: Russian>, 'level': <Level: Standard level>}, {}, {}, {}]
```

`serializer.serialize(cleaned_data)` does not works because there are `models` inside the `cleaned_data`.

Only way I probably figured out is to change all objects to it's primary keys and after deserialize get them from the database.

I want to serialize cleaned_data because I sending them to another view.

Comment: What is the desired outcome? i.e.: What would you like the serialized data to look like ideally? And what do you mean by "sending them to another view"? You've got the problem backwards. The model instances are not the problem, it's that the object you retrieved from the form isn't saved in the database yet, so it's not a model instance, but a dict. `serialize.serialize` applies to querysets or object instances, not to dicts, hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The `Django` way to do this is to use `model_to_dict`. This will serialize the model instance as a dictionary.  Call this on each model instance respectively in you `cleanded_data`

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

model_to_dict(model_instance)
```